# Two overlap gaussian mixtures come from one or two generations of data?

Tags: distribution, gaussian, gmm

Reviewing for a ML exam, my teacher asked last year a philosophical question about gaussians and generations of data which I couldn’t find no good answer.

Imagine that an oracle can say with 100% accuracy from what gaussian distribution comes every point generated by two **overlapped** gaussian mixtures. Is it possible to say that the points **come from a different generation**?

Thank you in advance.